# What are the Frequency Limits for Calls from chaincode to peer by invoking APIstub.PutState

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm trying to test the performance of Hyperledger Fabric. I've made a simple chaincode like this

```
// calculate account balance...

start := time.Now()
// 2. put balance into ledger
err = putLatestState(APIstub, accountID, newBalance)
if err != nil {
    transactionLogger.Error(err.Error())
    return shim.Error(err.Error())
}
transactionLogger.Infof("putLatestState, after %d", time.Now().Sub(start))

// do something
```

my `putLatestState()` function

```
func putLatestState(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, accountID string, newBalance string) error {
    key := accountID
    PutErr := APIstub.PutState(key, []byte(newBalance))
    if PutErr != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("Could not put balance for %s in the ledger: %s", accountID, PutErr.Error())
    }
    return nil
}
```

I want to note that I don't call any `GetState` to avoid read-write sets conflict.

When I call a single invoke (or concurrently about 100 requests at the same time), `putLatestState` **costs only ~0.2ms** (the logs below is in nanoseconds unit)

```
2020-12-08 19:33:20.463 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO bfb putLatestState, after 156297
2020-12-08 19:33:20.466 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO bfc putLatestState, after 171225
2020-12-08 19:33:20.470 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO bfd putLatestState, after 164062
2020-12-08 19:33:20.474 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO bfe putLatestState, after 163645
2020-12-08 19:33:20.478 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO bff putLatestState, after 125038
2020-12-08 19:33:20.483 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO c00 putLatestState, after 241095
2020-12-08 19:33:20.487 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO c01 putLatestState, after 203689
2020-12-08 19:33:20.492 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO c02 putLatestState, after 532434
2020-12-08 19:33:20.495 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO c03 putLatestState, after 166303
```

but when I send many many requests, it costs a lot **(3-9ms)**

```
2020-12-08 19:18:54.310 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO 4efc putLatestState, after 9374660
2020-12-08 19:18:54.310 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO 4efd putLatestState, after 9093387
2020-12-08 19:18:54.310 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO 4efe putLatestState, after 9070922
2020-12-08 19:18:54.310 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO 4eff putLatestState, after 9044761
2020-12-08 19:18:54.310 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO 4f00 putLatestState, after 8839449
2020-12-08 19:18:54.310 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO 4f01 putLatestState, after 8791697
2020-12-08 19:18:54.310 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO 4f02 putLatestState, after 8554055
2020-12-08 19:18:54.310 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO 4f03 putLatestState, after 8335684
2020-12-08 19:18:54.310 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO 4f04 putLatestState, after 8235291
2020-12-08 19:18:54.310 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO 4f05 putLatestState, after 8121222
2020-12-08 19:18:54.310 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO 4f06 putLatestState, after 7784521
2020-12-08 19:18:54.310 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO 4f07 putLatestState, after 7640421
2020-12-08 19:18:54.311 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO 4f08 putLatestState, after 7556968
2020-12-08 19:18:54.311 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO 4f09 putLatestState, after 7392899
2020-12-08 19:18:54.311 +07 [main.transaction] credit -> INFO 4f0a putLatestState, after 7066036
```

I think that could be a limitation between chaincode and peer. Hope that someone can help me solve this

Comment: First, what is the batch timeout setting value of the orderer?

Comment: Do you want to increase the processing speed of the transaction?

Comment: The batch timeout is 500ms. I'm trying to optimize the whole process, as fast as possible. Do you have any idea?

Comment: In fact, there are several ways. Many tricks are used. There are various methods that can be applied depending on the service. If I recall immediately...

Comment: First, if you are invoking the same data, modify so that all keys are invoked with different data.

Comment: Second, use Couchdb's queries. This includes querying data and querying through key values.

Comment: Third, if the data is independent, the channel or chain code is divided inside the blockchain, but it can be solved in parallel by building it in the form of managing it in the middleware framework.

Comment: Alternatively, there is a way to parallelize the organization or the peer itself.

Comment: Externally, there is a method of separately building a global cache DB and hitting it on the chaincode. Naturally, this is not correct because it is desirable to just use a centralized DB structurally and philosophically.

Comment: In addition, there are several advanced methods such as hardware acceleration or binary optimization of chaincode.

Comment: Thank you for much many information. I've stored the data locally on the chaincode, so I do not query any data from the ledger. This happens when I invoke this function with the different `accountID`s

Comment: I tried to measure the costs of every part of my chaincode. The PutState calling is not stable as I showed above :(